# Remove method for LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

So, I am trying to write two overloaded remove methods for LinkedList class, where one takes an index of an element that needs to be removed and another one that takes Object that needs to be removed. But when I try to make a LinkedList of integer and call the latter method, method that takes in index is called instead. Is there any way around this??
(PS. I know you can just change the name of the method, but I am given an interface file that requires me to write overloaded methods)

```
public E remove(int index) {

    for (int i = 0; i < index;i++) {
        curNode = curNode.next();
    }
    if (curNode == head && curNode == tail) {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }
    
    else {
        URNode sucNode = curNode.next();
        URNode prevNode = curNode.prev();
        if (sucNode != null)
            sucNode.setPrev(prevNode);
        else {
            prevNode.setNext(null);
            tail = prevNode;
        }
        if (prevNode != null)
            prevNode.setNext(sucNode);
        else {
            sucNode.setPrev(null);
            head = sucNode;
        }
    }
    numElements--;
    return null;
}


public boolean remove(Object o) {

    URNode curNode = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements;i++) {
        if (curNode.element() == o) {
            remove(i);
            return true;
        }
        curNode = curNode.next();
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    LinkedList intList = new LinkedList();
    intList.add(1);
    intList.add(2);
    intList.add(3);
    intList.remove(1);   //I want this to remove node with element 1, instead of node with index of 1
    //[2][3] should be returned, not [1][3]
}
```

Comment: Hi& Welcome!But wait: You say "overlaod" but it looks very like "override"!!!??

Comment: 1.: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove-int- (java8)..

Comment: 2.: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-

Comment: BUT, (of course ..with "boxing" and List<Integer>, not assigned result) these (two) methods already ambiguous... I need help, too!!

Comment: You'll need to call it `intList.remove(Integer.valueOf(1))`.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What I would do in this case is just not overload the names- especially since the overloads have different meanings. For example, you could rename them to "`removeAtIndex`"/"`removeAt`" and "`removeValue`".

Answer (score 0):

```java
intList.remove(Integer.valueOf(1)); // just make it Integer but not int
```

Comment: It works- that's for sure. It just seems to me like a confusing user-experience. I think the deeper problem the asker has is with usage of overloading.